# Jenkins: manually deploy build to different servers

Tags: jenkins

I have a project in Jenkins (web-application with many files). There are 5 servers where I want to deploy build if it is successful: 3 production and 2 test servers. However, automatic upload is required only for the first test server (for sure only if build is not broken). To the rest servers I want to deploy manually (ideally would be separately upload to the second test server and separately for 3 production servers).

So I would like to have something like list of buttons "Upload to server #1" on the build page and on the project page, near all the plots.

However, I couldn't find anything similar which would help me on that matter. I cannot believe, is really manual publish / deployment from admin panel some kind of exotic / extraordinary operation? Probably I try to resolve my problem in wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Build Pipeline plugin and add "Build other projects (manual step)" in post build action of job which uploads to first test server. Once pipeline created you can run manual steps in pipeline with Pipeline view.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin